# Terminal not running programs when pressing enter

Tags: macos, terminal

Command line isn't properly running programs

After trying to run a program on terminal it doesn't execute properly and just makes a new line with > at the start

How can I fix this

Comment: Press Control-C to return to the prompt, then look at  Edward Falk's answer.

Comment: It's helpful if you provide the command you are trying to execute.  See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a single " or ' somewhere in your command line arguments. Maybe something like this:

```
echo It's a nice day
```

The command line is waiting for the matching " or '. That's what the > means.

You can fix this by quoting the entire argument with the other kind of quote:

```
echo "It's a nice day"
```

Or escaping the offending character with \

```
echo It\'s a nice day
```